# Connect from docker container to host elasticsearch runing instance

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have this simple setup:
A Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:latest
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y epel-release
RUN yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk
RUN yum install -y curl
RUN mkdir /var/totest
EXPOSE 9200
EXPOSE 9300
```

And on host machine I have a running instance of elasticsearch 5.4.2.

When I do on host curl http://localhost:9200 I get the correct response:

```
  {
  "name" : "T8apV_J",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "YFkkaM8dSJCnXbDFRFD_aw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.4.2",
    "build_hash" : "929b078",
    "build_date" : "2017-06-15T02:29:28.122Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.5.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

but, if i build the docker image and I run

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -it my-simple-image /bin/bash
```

I get this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint infallible_brown (71c6fae1275d149b2708a1aa9b737278d340c4e7b073d858b4222eb0268ef285): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:9200: bind: address already in use.
```

How can I connect from inside the docker container to the host running elasticsearch instance?

All I need is to be able to perform from inside the container

curl http://localhost:9200/index_name/_search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elastic search uses port 9200. Now you want to publish port 9200 from a container to localhost. You can not have two applications listening on the same port of localhost.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `EXPOSE 9200` directive in the `Dockerfile` because port number 9200 is already taken by the elastic search service.

You should `curl` with the ip address of your host machine.
Docker attaches containers to the `bridge` network to start with so you need a way to get the ip address of the host.

You may need to set an alias depending on whether or not your host is connected to a wider network. I set this alias for my `bridge0` interface.

```
sudo ifconfig bridge0 alias <ip_address>
```

If your host connected to a wider network, use the `inet` address of assigned to your ethernet device. You can get the `inet` address by running:

```
ifconfig en0 | grep "inet " | cut -d " " -f2
```

You can either way pass the `inet` address of your network interface as an environment variable to docker:

```
docker run -e MY_HOST_IP=$(ip_address) -it my-simple-image /bin/bash
# or
docker run -e MY_HOST_IP=$(ifconfig en0 | grep "inet " | cut -d " " -f2) -it my-simple-image /bin/bash

curl $MY_HOST_IP:8000
```

[See this thread for more information about your question](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22753)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick hack to get it working. With Elastic accessible on your host with `curl -X GET 'http://0.0.0.0:9200'`, I think `docker run --net host --name your_app` will allow the container'd app to query the Elastic instance running on your host. So, you can omit any `EXPOSE` or `-p` settings. But be aware, according to their docs:

> --network="host" gives the container full access to local system services such as D-bus and is therefore considered insecure.